# Cocos2d restart current scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've got an end of level layer added to game, each level has its own scene. I want to be able to restart the current scene. Obviously the scene will change but the layer will remain the same. How is this done. I've tried-

```
    CCScene *currentScene = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]runningScene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:currentScene];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not work because you can't replace the same scene object with itself:

```
CCScene *currentScene = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]runningScene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:currentScene];
```

Instead you have to create a new instance of your scene, like so:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[YourSceneClass scene]];
```

If you don't know what the current scene class is, then this ought to work:

```
CCScene *currentScene = [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene;
CCScene *newScene = [[[currentScene class] alloc] init];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:newScene];
```

Assuming you're using ARC as everyone should these days. Otherwise add an autorelease.

Comment: As you say the scene will vary so I tried the last way you mentioned but this just seems to give me a blank scene?

Comment: Could my problem be that I'm doing it in a layer added to the scene?

Comment: just make shure that you use the same constructor that was used for initial creation of your scene. i mean, if you create your scene like initWithSomParameter: , you need to call this constructor is you do not had implement default init method

Comment: Still havent been able to get this to work. my scene doesnt have any parameters so its not that?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I tried this

```
CCScene *currentScene = [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene;
CCScene *newScene = [[[currentScene class] alloc] init];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:newScene];
```

and it gave me a blank screen.

The problem is this line

```
CCScene *newScene = [[[currentScene class] alloc] init];
```

[currentScene class] actually returns CCScene..

Hence

```
[CCScene alloc] init] gives us a blank screen.
```

The way how I got around this problem was by setting tag for each of my scene class.

For example:

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    scene.tag = 1;

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
GameOneLayer * layer = [[[GameOneLayer alloc] init];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}
```

Hope this helps.